# Which compiler is correct for this subtle ternary operator code example, gcc or clang?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template<template<class, class, class...> class Map, typename Key, typename T, typename KeyP, typename... Args>
const T& getMapEntry(const Map<Key, T, Args...>& map, const KeyP& key, const T& defval) {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<KeyP, Key>);
    auto i = map.find(key);
    return i != map.end() ? i->second : defval;
}

template<template<class, class, class...> class Map, typename Key, typename T, typename KeyP, typename... Args>
T getMapEntry(const Map<Key, T, Args...>& map, const KeyP& key, T&& defval) {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<KeyP, Key>);
    auto i = map.find(key);
    return i != map.end() ? i->second : std::move(defval);
}

template<template<class, class, class...> class Map, typename Key, typename T, typename KeyP, typename... Args>
T getMapEntry(const Map<Key, T, Args...>& map, const KeyP& key, const T&& defval) = delete;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return *this; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, Foo> map;
    auto&& ret = getMapEntry(map, 123U, Foo{});
    return 0;
}
```

gcc outputs:

```
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo(Foo&&)
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
```

clang outputs:

```
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo(const Foo &)
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
```

Using an if/else chain always invokes the move ctor.  Using the following line, which is more revealing, also causes the move ctor to be invoked:

```
return i != map.end() ? T{i->second} : std::move(defval);
```

Which implementation is correct?

Comment: How do you compile the code? Different compiles and compiler versions have different default C++ standard presets.

Comment: Most recent version of both.  -std=c++17 is sufficient.  If anything non-standard was required, I would have specified it.

Comment: This boils down to what's the expected result of a ternary when one is an lvalue and the other is an rvalueref. I think gcc is wrong here. It looks like it's optimizing both sides of the ternary, separately, to initialize the returned `T`, and for the side that produces an rvalueref it's generating a move, and for the side that produces a lvalue it must be generating a copy. This doesn't sound kosher to me.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the first overload to reproduce the behavior. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xn8EM38bq).

Comment: @MarkB You can remove the first overload and make the code [reduced](https://godbolt.org/z/xn8EM38bq)

Comment: In the second overload, you probably want `std::forward<T>(defval)` instead of `std::move(defval)` to be on the safe side. It doesn't change the behavior in your example, though.

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me as it chooses `const Foo&` in the reduced [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xn8EM38bq)

Comment: I feel like the issue is somewhere around copy-elision rules and the problem that `defval` is a function parameter. For example, changing it to `return i != map.end() ? i->second : T(std::forward<T>(defval));` causes both to appropriately invoke the move constructor.

Comment: @AndyG Copy-elision shouldn't be an issue here as `std::move` is used explicitly. In fact both the 1st and the 3rd overload can be removed and that will still reproduce the behavior. See in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/caf9Pe6fT) I've removed both the 1st and 3rd overload and now only the 2nd overload where `std::move` is used explicitly reproduces the issue.

Comment: @user12002570 I was basing my comment on the fact that `std::common_type_T<const Foo&, Foo&&>` results in a type of `Foo`, meaning that the code is effectively returning `Foo(i != map.end() ? ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question surrounds what happens during:

- evaluation of a ternary, and
- possible copy elision

The expression:

```
return i != map.end() ? i->second : std::move(defval);
```

per [[expr.cond]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond)

Will attempt to find an implicit conversion sequence between `i->second` and `std::move(defval)` (both directions).

- `i->second` (expression 1, or E1) is an lvalue
- `std::move(defval)` (expression 2 or E2) is an xvalue

[[expr.cond 4.2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#4.2) states:

> If E2 is an xvalue, the target type is “rvalue reference to T2”, but an implicit conversion sequence can only be formed if the reference would bind directly.

And this *almost* applies; we'd allow an lvalue to rvalue conversion only if the lvalue could be bound without invoking a copy. Unfortunately this rule cannot be used becaue `i->second` cannot be converted to an rvalue without a copy, so we fall back to [[4.3.3]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#4.3.3) which states:

> [...] otherwise, the target type is the type that E2 would have after applying the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions.

Meaning the return type will be a prvalue, and we finally have to deal with lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `i->second`, which necessitates a copy, per [[conv.lval]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#conv.lval-3.2) (an xvalue is also a glvalue, which allows this conversion to apply)

> Otherwise, if T has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes the result object from the glvalue.

So we're ultimately returning an prvalue, which has mandatory copy-elision. This is why there is not yet-another constructor call logged to the console.

Therefore the correct behavior in this case is to see a call to the copy-constructor of `Foo`, and clang is correct.

If you want to enforce that move construction happens in your case, you cannot use a ternary expression:

```
    if (i != map.end())
       return i->second;
    else
        return std::move(defval);
```

This will ensure that both compilers call the move constructor of `Foo` if the `else` branch is invoked.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113791

Comment: "Copy-initialize"/copy-initialization does not necessite a call to copy-constructor.

Comment: @cpplearner not always, no. But it can, and here I believe it shall.